# Max Length of a column in a DataTable in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, datatable

I have found this code in a website that can find the Max Length of a column in a DataTable in PowerShell. Here is the code:

```
$columns = ($datatable | Get-Member -MemberType Property).Name

foreach($column in $Columns) {

    $max = 0
    foreach ($a in $datatable){
        if($max -lt $a.$column.length){
            $max = $a.$column.length
        }
    }

    $output = New-Object psobject
    $output | Add-Member NoteProperty Column ($column)
    $output | Add-Member NoteProperty Max ($max)

    Write-Output $output
}
```

it does find the max length in a column, however it give me this result:

```
Column Max 
A       3
A       4
A       5
B      10
C      19
C      29
D       9
```

the file only have 4 columns and have about 300k+ rows
the biggest value in Max is the actual max characters in a column, the result will export as csv file and it then have other use. so I don't to have those extra rows in the csv file.

what went wrong with the loop?

thank you

edit:

this is the rest of the code:

```
$FileHeaders = @( (Get-Content $files -first 1).Split($delimiter) )

#take out all the nonword/number character in header
$CleanHeaders = @(($FileHeaders.Split("$delimiter") -replace "[^a-zA-Z0-9_]", "").ToLower())

$readfiles = Get-Item $files

#create the streamreader
$reader = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.StreamReader -ArgumentList ($readfiles)

#create a data table
$datatable = New-Object -TypeName System.Data.DataTable

#insert the header to the columen headers
foreach ( $CleanHeader in $CleanHeaders ) {

     [void]$datatable.Columns.Add($CleanHeader)

}

$reader.ReadLine() > $null

#call the streamreader to read the files
while ( $reader.Peek() -ge 0 ) {

      $line = $reader.ReadLine()

      #import the data into the table                                                                                
      [void]$datatable.Rows.Add($line.Split($delimiter))
}
```

$files and $delimiter already defined.

Comment: The loop looks fine and reports the property values for me with the test .csv I made. I can't see what $datatable is so I don't know if that is configured correctly. I used Import-Csv and updated the "Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty,Property" to accommodate for Import-Csv.

Comment: I don't have a problem with this code, though I don't have a 300k+ line file. Have you considered using `$Columns = $datatable.Columns.ColumnName` to get your names? What version of PowerShell are you using?

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, but still have the same problem, I do have another method, but it is much slower `foreach ($column in $columns) { $max = ($datatable | select -ExpandProperty $column | Measure-Object -Maximum -Property Length).Maximum }` Any improvement to make it faster? and why it is a lot slower than the other methods?